# Does "another" mean "another" in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I sometimes hear people saying something like

> Let $f$ be a function from a set $A$ into *another* set $B$.

But, of course, by saying this, they do not want to exclude the possibility of $A$ and $B$ being equal, they just mean that $B$ can be different than $A$.

My question is: Is it, technically speaking, correct to use the word "another" in this case? Also, independent of the question whether "another" is correct or not, I wonder if the word "another" could confuse readers oder listeners, that is, if the word "another" is good from an expository point of view.

Comment: That is not a "technical" sentence.  One speaker may be using "another" to indicate that $A \ne B$, while a different speaker might not care to make that distinction, and is only using the word as a bit of verbal filler.  If one wanted to be clear, would write "$f : A \to B$ where $A \ne B$".

Comment: It's generally best to be as clear as possible.  Why use "another" when you could just say "into a set $B$" and avoid any possible confusion?

Comment: This is a question better suited for ELU.se than it is for math.se

Comment: It's not "technical", but it's a prevalent part of the language of mathematicians speaking informally, and it is used only when in _some cases_ $B$ is a different set.

Comment: It would have been better to write "/.../ into a possible different set $B$".

Comment: @amWhy While I agree that the question is about English language usage, and not strictly math, the question is so fundamentally rooted in conventional mathematical jargon that I suspect the community there would suggest that the question be asked here in order to better reach an audience who can actually help.

Comment: That may very well be, @Arthur.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm having trouble parsing your sentence, but it seems that you are asserting that `another` is "used only" in certain contexts.  Do you have any evidence of this claim, or is it just an opinion?  As far as I can tell, the usage is *informal*, not technical, and has no fixed, universally accepted meaning.  Indeed, it would probably be a poor choice to use the quoted sentence in a formal publication, but it could be entirely appropriate in verbal communication, where it is possible to give additional context from non-verbal cues.

Comment: I disagree that this question is better suited for the English Language & Usage site, so I created a meta post to ask for more comments: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29111/are-questions-about-mathematical-language-writing-and-terminology-on-topic-her

Comment: I disagree that this question should be closed as "primarily opinion based". Yes, the interpretation of the sentence is primarily opinion based - but then the OP (and those who use similar statements) should realise this. Therefore, the question admits a non-opinion based answer: the statement is ambiguous and should be rewritten.

Comment: Is it technically correct? Yes, just like saying "let $x$ and $y$ be two real numbers" technically allows the numbers to be equal. But, like that usage, it may confuse readers who expect the non-technical connotation that "another" means "a distinct" and "two" means "two distinct".  In mathematical writing, it is necessary to explicitly say that objects are distinct to guarantee that is what the reader will take away.

Comment: @CarlMummert: And there is no real way around the number issue; we do often say "let $x,y$ be positive reals ..." or some such, and almost surely we do not mean they need to be distinct just because we used the plural word "reals", or alternatively "real numbers".

Comment: Related question: What is the cardinality of the set $\{a,b\}$? The answer could be $1$ or $2$ ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is common usage but it really isn't a good thing. If one means that the set is distinct just say a "distinct set B." If B is possibly A then just say "from A to B" without any further comment. To some extent "another" in this context is a verbal "filler" that doesn't do much.

For that matter, it seems unlikely that there are going to be many contexts where one has a function from A to B and it is going to matter that A is not B while at the same time there won't be other stronger properties in use like A and B differing in cardinality or topology or metric.

Comment: Is this a common usage?  Do you have any evidence to back up that claim?  I can't say that I've ever seen it in print, and the number of times that I've heard anything like it in verbal communication in my career can probably be counted on one hand.

Comment: @XanderHenderson That's a valid question; my impression is that it isn't an uncommon thing to say but I don't have any concrete evidence of this. I don't think I've seen it in writing ever.

Comment: To strengthen this answer: the "another" in the OP's quoted sentence makes sense only at the very meta level where we are distinguishing between different names for the same object; since this is not the intention, I'd say that inserting "another" in said sentence is even *wrong* (as opposed to merely introducing ambiguity), for this explicitly excludes the possibility that $A=B.$